# Possion distribution question

Tags: probability

[image: [enter image description here]

From the possion distribution formulat I get $$P[X = x] = e^{-6} \frac{6^x}{x!}$$. But what do I do with the x when it is an interval? Thanks

Comment: A Poisson variable takes integer values. The integers in your interval are $5$, $6$, $7$, $8$ and $9$.

Comment: Sorry for the spam. Do i just do $$P[X = 5] = e^{-7} \frac{7^5}$$ + ... +  $$P[X = 9] = e^{-7} \frac{7^9}$$

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

- Just sum up the the integet values in that range. That is compute $P(X=5)+P(X+6)+\ldots + P(X=9)$. You might like to write a loop or use a list comprehension.
- Currently you are using the wrong parameter, for this question, $\lambda = 7$.

Comment: So sum up   $$P[X = 5] = e^{-7} \frac{7^5}$$ + ... +  $$P[X = 9] = e^{-7} \frac{7^9}$$

Comment: yup, don't forget the factorial term in the denominator.